# Continuous Integration - Running parallel tests suites that require xvfb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, continuous-integration, x11, xvfb

I'm having issues with parallel builds running that require an xvfb server. I was previously using the `headless` ruby gem, but had sporadic failures when certain test suites that both require `capybara-webkit` and an xvfb server are running in parallel.

My guess was that they were both trying to use the same DISPLAY, so I attempted to set different DISPLAY values and then run them in parallel, but there was still a failure.

I then tried removing the `headless` gem and running my test suite with:
`DISPLAY=localhost:$display_num.0 xvfb-run bundle exec rake` where `$display_num` is a previously set bash variable that is different between the two test suites.

I then get the error: `xvfb-run: error: Xvfb failed to start` when they were run in parallel.

Any assistance on deciphering this would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the gist](https://gist.github.com/rosskevin/5937888), but ultimately you need to start one `headless` per process.

This is effectively done with the `features/support/javascript.rb` file referenced in the gist, the relevant section being:

```
# Unnecessary on mac
if (!OS.mac? && !$headless_started)

    require 'headless'
    # allow display autopick (by default)
    # allow each headless to destroy_at_exit (by default)
    # allow each process to have their own headless by setting reuse: false
    headless_server = Headless.new(:reuse => false)
    headless_server.start

    $headless_started = true
    puts "Process[#{Process.pid}] started headless server display: #{headless_server.display}"
end
```